# set old value = old value + new value ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql

I see this example and i want update old values with old values + new values

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
(2, 'a2', 'b2', 'c2'),
(3, 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'),
(4, 'a4', 'b4', 'c4'),
(5, 'a5', 'b5', 'c5'),
(6, 'a6', 'b6', 'c6')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
a=VALUES(old a+ new a),
b=VALUES(old b+ new b),
c=VALUES(old c+ new c);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks I've solved my problem

```
INSERT INTO mytable (id, a, b, c)
VALUES (1, 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
(2, '5', '6', '7'),
(3, '5', '6', '7'),
(4, '5', '6', '7'),
(5, '5', '6', '7'),
(6, '5', '6', '7')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=VALUES(id),
a=a+VALUES(a),
b=b+VALUES(b),
c=c+VALUES(c);
```